# Advance Custom Filed Get Field for Terms not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Want to display the category icon in the post list, for that, I'm creating a custom field category_icon field by using ACF.
below is my code to get the icon image URL, but not getting anything even no error also.

```
<span class="blog-info-categories">
<?php
print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '' );
$terms = get_terms('category');?>
<?php
$taxonomy = 'category';
// Get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids'));

// Separator between links.
$separator = ', ';
if (!empty($post_terms) && !is_wp_error($post_terms)) {
$term_ids = implode(',', $post_terms);
$terms = wp_list_categories(array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'style'    => 'none',
        'echo'     => false,
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'include'  => $term_ids));

$terms = rtrim(trim(str_replace('<br />',  $separator, $terms)),   $separator);                                                                 $termss = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID,array( 'category' ) );
$icon = get_field('category_icon', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_ids);
echo $icon['url'];
echo  $terms;
}
?>
</span>
```

[image: i]

Comment: Are you trying to show a different icon for each term in the taxonomy "Category" that has bee added to each term page? Where is your ACF group set to appear? Could you send a screenshot of your ACF field group location.

Comment: yes, I want different icons for different category. so I already add a field in the category taxonomy.

Comment: So you want a list of category terms e.g.
ICON Category Term, ICON Category Term

Comment: https://snag.gy/tQuPR9.jpg this the screenshot.

Comment: yes.list with icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wp_list_categories() function outputs a html list which is a string I would always use get_terms() so I have something to loop through. Is this a solution to your problem? I think I understand but can revise the solution to suit if I'm wrong.

```
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'include'  => $post_terms
    )
);

foreach($terms as $term){
    $icon = get_field('category_icon', $term);
    $icon = $icon['url'];
    $name = $term->name;
    $url = get_term_link($term, $taxonomy);
    echo '<img src="' . $icon . '">' . '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $name . '</a>, ';
}
```